# How do I install php curl for phpfarm?

Tags: php, curl

`composer install` gives error:

```
Problem 1
- guzzle/guzzle v3.9.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- guzzle/guzzle v3.9.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- Installation request for guzzle/guzzle v3.9.3 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.3].
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
- /opt/phpfarm/inst/php-5.4.45/lib/php.ini
```

I use phpfarm for multiple php version. During installation settings are not specified (for example, `configoptions="\  –with-curl \  ... "`).

How can I fix this now and install extensions?

Comment: check if curl is enabled in php extensions.